# How can I move the created content of a <div1> into a <div2> without moving the whole <div1> and keep creating elements in <div1>?

Tags: javascript, function, appendchild

I'm trying to code a to do list with vanilla JS/Html in which elements from "To Do" can end up in "Done" when clicked. I have made my icons clickable, I have managed to move content from one div to the other, but I have several issues and I can't seem to find the problem lies:

1: Why does my JS script move my whole 'doList' div into my 'doneList' div when I (thought I) asked for it to move the `<li id=todotask>` only? is it a parent problem? (line 24)

2: How do I manage to move only ONE `<li>` element, the one I click, and not the others? Right now they all get the same ID upon appearing so I guess that's going to be a problem, so...

3: Is there a way I can give every `<li>` a different ID and change the moved `<li>` element's ID after I click it?

4: When I finally get my `<li>` element in the right div after click, how can I "restart" my function so the next `<li>` element I put in my input appears in "todo" and not in "done" after the one I moved?

Here is what I've read and tried so far : changing the parent and the child in my moveItem function, give an ID to my `<li>` elements upon creation, removing and adding an ID using li.id and classList.remove/add, read at least 50 SO answers on how to move divs into one another but didn't find anything that would fit my need, since I want to move a .createElement created `<li>` onclick and be done with it, not have a div move by itself, move elemenets that are already in my html or fuse content of two divs...

Here is my JS code:

```js
function newItem() {
  console.log("Inside newItem")

  //set variables
  let item = document.getElementById("taskinput").value;
  let ul = document.getElementById('doList');
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = 'todotask';

// now put text in list item
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  ul.appendChild(li); // put list item in our unordered list
  document.getElementById("taskinput").value = ""; // erase what is currently in todo
  li.onclick = moveItem; // run moveItem when the li is clicked
}

function moveItem(e) {
  var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement == doneList ? todotask : doneList;
  moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
  console.log("Item Moved to Done")
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {

  let item = document.getElementById("taskinput").value;
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter pressed!');
    newItem();
    console.log(item);
  };
};

document.getElementById('addtask').onclick = function() {
  console.log('Add button pressed!')
  newItem()
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="addtaskbar">
      <input type="text" name="taskinput" id="taskinput" placeholder="What do you have to do next?">
      <input type="button" name="addtask" id="addtask" value="Add">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="todo">
      <ul id='doList'>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="done">
      <ul id='doneList'>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```

here is what it shows on my inspector before and after I move my elements:

Before:

[image: 1]

After:

[image: 2]

Comment: You're moving `this.parentElement` rather than `this`.

Comment: Gosh thank you Barmar, and for the editing as well, very sorry about that, changed to moveTo.appendChild(this) and it does exactly what it's supposed to!

Comment: having a duplicate `id` in HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `moveItem`, `this` is the `ul`. So you should be moving `this`, not `this.parentElement`.

Also, `doList` or `doneList` will be the parent of the element, not the grandparent, so you need to change the condition in the ternary expression.

And the destination when moving back should be `doList`, `todotask` is the ID of a specific task. You also shouldn't create duplicate IDs like that. There's no need to give an ID to the tasks that are created dynamically.

```js
function newItem() {
  console.log("Inside newItem")

  //set variables
  let item = document.getElementById("taskinput").value;
  let ul = document.getElementById('doList');
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  // now put text in list item
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  ul.appendChild(li); // put list item in our unordered list
  document.getElementById("taskinput").value = ""; // erase what is currently in todo
  li.onclick = moveItem; // run moveItem when the li is clicked
}

function moveItem(e) {
  var moveTo = this.parentElement == doneList ? doList : doneList;
  moveTo.appendChild(this);
  console.log("Item Moved to " + (moveTo == doneList ? "Done" : "ToDo"))
}

document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {

  let item = document.getElementById("taskinput").value;
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('enter pressed!');
    newItem();
    console.log(item);
  };
};

document.getElementById('addtask').onclick = function() {
  console.log('Add button pressed!')
  newItem()
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="addtaskbar">
      <input type="text" name="taskinput" id="taskinput" placeholder="What do you have to do next?">
      <input type="button" name="addtask" id="addtask" value="Add">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    To Do
    <div id="todo">
      <ul id='doList'>

      </ul>
    </div>
    Done:
    <div id="done">
      <ul id='doneList'>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't really know what you mean by "changing the if test" though?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the condition in the ternary expression. `this.parentElement.parentElement == doneList` should be `this.parentElement == doneList`